# Export data by following JSON Schema

Tags: mongodb

I have many fields on my MongoDB, but I want to export only these out which appear on my JSON Schema.

This is my JSON schema, I want these fields to .CSV:

```json
{
  "names": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "order": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "registrationDate": "",
      "endDate": "",
      "name": "",
      "language": ""
    }
  ],
  "auxiliaryNames": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "order": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "registrationDate": "",
      "endDate": "",
      "name": "",
      "language": ""
    }
  ],
  "addresses": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "version": 0,
      "registrationDate": "",
      "endDate": "",
      "careOf": "",
      "street": "",
      "postCode": "",
      "city": "",
      "language": "",
      "type": 0,
      "country": ""
    }
  ]
```

Comment: in which technology , node js?

Comment: It's JSON data on my mongoDB (localhost). I'm beginner with these, so I dont know was this right answer :)

Comment: i mean which techology are you using for this? Node , java or python??

Comment: I got data to mongoDB from PHP JSON API by using Python. Sorry I'm beginner with these things :-)

Comment: mongo always return JSON data and it can not be convert to csv file using the mongo. you need to write code in python for this.

Comment: Alright, thank you. This case can be closed then, need to find someone to write code for it.